# How to overwrite error messages for Not Null items of Model generated by Phalcon-devtools?

Tags: php, phalcon

### Question

Validation rules for `PresenceOf` are automatically set for items for which the Not Null constraint is set on the table definition for the model generated by Phalcon-devtools, but at the same time as the message "***name is required***" at the time of PresenceOf error It will be automatically done.

You do not have to change the Validation rule of `PresenceOf`, but please teach me how to overwrite this error message.

---

### Overview

- Generate Model with Phalcon-devtools with the following command.

  ```
  phalcon model user
  ```
- Even if you do not set the validation rule specially, if you save it without inputting it for the input item `name` of Not Null, an error occurs and you can acquire the message "***name is required***".
- To make the error message your own string, add the following to the User model.

  ```
  $validator = new Validation();
      $validator->add(
         'name',
          new PresenceOf([
             'message' => "required",
          ])
      );
  ```
- It was an assumption to acquire "***required***" as a error message, but the result does not change and it gets "***name is required***".

---

### Source code

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf;

class User extends ModelBase
{
    /**
     *
     * @var string
     * @Column(type="string", length=767, nullable=false)
     */
    public $name;

    public function validation()
    {
        $validator = new Validation();

        $validator->add(
            'name',
            new PresenceOf([
                'message' => "required",
            ])
        );

        return $this->validate($validator);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize method for model.
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSchema("lashca");
        $this->setSource("user");
    }

    /**
     * Returns table name mapped in the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * Allows to query a set of records that match the specified conditions
     *
     * @param mixed $parameters
     * @return User[]|User|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultSetInterface
     */
    public static function find($parameters = null)
    {
        return parent::find($parameters);
    }

    /**
     * Allows to query the first record that match the specified conditions
     *
     * @param mixed $parameters
     * @return User|\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\ResultInterface
     */
    public static function findFirst($parameters = null)
    {
        return parent::findFirst($parameters);
    }

}
```

---

### Environment

- CentOS 7.4(x64)
- Apache 2.4.6
- PHP 7.0.26
- Phalcon Framework 3.2.4
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set a default value directly into your model variables

```
 /**
 *
 * @var string
 * @Column(type="string", length=767, nullable=false)
 */
public $name = '';
```

Another thing you could do is setup the default value from the database directly and pass the 'default' RawValue as value

```
protected function beforeValidationOnCreate() {
    if (empty($this->name)) {
        $this->name = new \Phalcon\Db\RawValue('default');
    }
}
```

Finally you can disable the default phalcon validation

```
 public function initialize() {
    $this->setup(array('notNullValidations' => false));
}
```

Comment: Thnak you for your advice. 
I seemed to be highly versatile, I corresponded in the following way.
`$this->setup(array('notNullValidations' => false));`